# Why Does It Take My EC2 Mac Instance So Much Longer To Start And Stop?

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2

I have created/started/stopped EC2 instances of Ubuntu, Windows, and Mac. The Windows and Ubuntu instances start and stop within 1 min.

However, the Mac instances take at least 2 min before I can log on to it and almost 15 min to show  "Stopped"  when I shut it down.

To create the Mac instance I had to allocate a dedicated server. I'm assuming this server is still virtual and not a physical machine?

My question is why does it take the Mac instances so much longer to start and stop?